# Why are my Razor Pages forms not posting to the correct handlers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, partial-views, razor-pages

I'm building a web application using ASP.NET Core 3.0. I have a model called `Article`. I am having problems in two parts of my application where neither editing nor deleting an article are calling the correct `POST` method handlers.

My `Article` class is defined as follows in the namespace `Models`:

*Models/Articles.cs*

```cs
public class Article
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [StringLength(32)]
  public string Title { get; set; }

  [StringLength(512)]
  public string Description { get; set; }

  public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

---

**Editing**

I have a shared partial view called `_Editor.cshtml`. It is defined as follows:

*Pages/Articles/_Editor.cshtml*

```html
@model Models.Article

<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label col-xs-4 col-md-2"></label>
    <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control col-xs-8 col-md-10" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger col"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label col-xs-4 col-md-2"></label>
    <textarea asp-for="Description" class="form-control col-xs-8 col-md-10" style="height:4em"></textarea>
    <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger col"></span>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Content" class="control-label col-xs-4 col-md-2"></label>
    <textarea asp-for="Content" class="form-control col-xs-8 col-md-10" style="height:16em"></textarea>
    <span asp-validation-for="Content" class="text-danger col"></span>
</div>
```

I use this partial view from inside both the `Edit.cshtml` and `Create.cshtml` files as follows:

*Pages/Articles/Edit.cshtml*

```html
@page
@model Pages.Articles.EditModel

<form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Article.Id" />
    <partial name="_Editor" model="Model.Article" />

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</div>

</form>
```

*Pages/Articles/Create.cshtml*

```html
@page
@model Pages.Articles.CreateModel

<form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <partial name="_Editor" model="Model.Article" />

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Both of these Razor pages have standard scaffolded code-behind (.cshtml.cs) files. **The create page works successfully but the edit page does not actually save the edits.**

---

**Deleting**

On my `View.cshtml` Razor Page, I want to have an article delete dialog that can be used in other pages throughout the project. I use the `Delete.cshtml` partial view for this. It's code is as follows:

*Pages/Articles/Delete.cshtml*

```html
@model Models.Article

<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="deletionModal">
    <form id="deletionModalForm" asp-page="Articles/Delete" method="post">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Delete Article</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Are you sure you want to delete the article "@Model.Title"?</p>

                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Id" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

It is referenced in the `View.cshtml` Razor page as follows:

*Pages/Articles/View.cshtml*

```html
@page
@model Comprehension.Pages.Articles.ViewModel

<partial name="Delete" model="Model.Article" />

<div class="row mb-4">
    <h2 class="col">@Model.Article.Title</h2>
    <p class="col-auto">
        <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.Article.Id" class="text-primary">Edit</a>
    </p>
    <p class="col-auto">
        <a class="text-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deletionModal">Delete</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

These two pages have code-behind (.cshtml.cs) files that were scaffolded in the usual way. **Whenever the submit button is pressed in `Delete.cshtml`, the `OnPost` method in `View.cshtml.cs` is called rather than the `OnPost` method in `Delete.cshtml.cs`.**

I've tried adding `@page` to the `Delete.cshtml` to no avail. I've also tried everything as suggested by @Xing Zou.

---

It seems to me that these two issues originate from the same mistake but I'm not sure what that mistake is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For context, here is a screenshot of my project structure.

[image: Directory structure of my ASP.NET Razor Pages Project]

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that , you click a button (named Delete) firstly, then a shared dialog pop up, you could see `Title` in the dialog to confirm .Finally, click the `Delete` button in the dialog to call the actual post handler to delete the article.

Below is my simple demo:

1._Delete.cshtml

Add `id` for the model and add `<form>` tag to submit to your delete handler

```
@model Models.Article
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal">
    <form id="myForm" method="post">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Delete Article</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Are you sure you want to delete the article "@Model.Title"?</p>

                    @*Pass current article ID*@
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Id" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" asp-page="Articles/Delete"  class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </form>
</div>
```

2.Index.cshtml:

```
<partial name="_Delete" model="@Model.Article" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary myButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Delete
</button>
```

3.Pages/Articles/Delete.cshtml(Delete.cshtml.cs) Razor Page

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int? id)
{
 //your delete logic
}
```

[image]

***Edit 12/24/2019***

Do not put partial view as razor pages, you just need to submit to a post hanlder behind one razor page.

Besides,`asp-page` should use correct path, if you put your partial view in the same Articles folder,then it will change to `asp-page="Delete"`

Demo:

1.Create a partial view as `Pages/Articles/MyDeletePartilaView.cshtml`:

```
@model Models.Article

<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="deletionModal">
    <form id="deletionModalForm" asp-page="Delete" method="post">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Delete Article</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Are you sure you want to delete the article "@Model.Title"?</p>

                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Id" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

2.Pages/Articles/View.cshtml

```
 <partial name="MyDeletePartilaView.cshtml" model="Model.Article" />
```

3.Pages/Articles/Delete.cshtml

```
@page
@model RazorpagesCore.Pages.Movies.DeleteModel
```

4.Pages/Articles/Delete.cshtml.cs

```
public class DeleteModel : PageModel
{
   public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int? id)
    {
       //your delete logic         

    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I tried this. It seems like the `OnPostAsync` in `Delete.cshtml.cs` isn't actually getting called though. I did some debugging and the form ends up posting to `Index.cshtml.cs`. Have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @Matthew Miller  It is likely that `asp-page` is not set correct in your case,you could always press F12 to check the `formaction` attribute of the button.in my sample, `_Delete.cshtml` under `Pages/Shared/_Delete.cshtml` and that Post handler under `Pages/Articles/Delete.cshtml`.

Comment: I've verified that I have the same setup but the post handler in `Index.cshtml.cs` is still being called rather than the one in `Delete.cshtml.cs`. I checked the generated HTML by the application and the button has no form action: `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" formaction="">Delete</button>`.

Comment: Also, I am having the same problem in a different portion of the application with another partial view if that helps provide context. The submit button is essentially posting to the wrong handlers in both instances.

Comment: @Matthew Miller It's strange.Your `formaction=""` is the problem I think,the url is not generated correctly...Could you show your structure of your project (screenshot)?

Comment: I've uploaded a screenshot of my project structure into my original question.

Comment: @Matthew Miller `asp-page="Articles/Delete"` finds a razor page `Pages/Articles/Delete.cshtml` while you do not have the page.Maybe I do not explain that clearly, you should not only have the `Delete.cshtml.cs`, `asp-page` is used for page name.See my edit

Comment: I've tried this but it still does not work. I've updated my original question with more information. Let me know if you have any more ideas. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Matthew Miller Do not mix partial view and razor pages.If you want to put a partial view in the Articles, the post handler could be in any `.cshtml.cs`.My sample is demo to use the scaffold `Delete.cshtml.cs`, you could have your own `MyDeletePartilaView.cshtml` in Articles and post to the hanlder in Delete page.See my edit.

Comment: I've already tried both methods. Both separating into partial view and page as well as combining the two perform the same way. Also, it does not explain my error with my `_Editor.cshtml` page.